# How can I get the updated price from this site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

So I am making a basic finance site as a project but I can't figure out how to get the new price after I get the original price and do stuff based on the new price.

Here's what I have now

```
function getPrice() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=' + $("#stock").val(),
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function(json) {
            $("#stockprice").html(json[0]['l']);    
        }
    });
}

$("#getstock").click(getPrice);
```

I just need to get the updated price, then I'll go from there.

For example, if the user types in 'AMD' then the JSON would look like this

```
// [ { "id": "327" ,"t" : "AMD" ,"e" : "NASDAQ" ,"l" : "13.74" ,"l_fix" : "13.74" ,"l_cur" : "13.74" ,"s": "0" ,"ltt":"3:04PM EDT" ,"lt" : "Mar 29, 3:04PM EDT" ,"lt_dts" : "2017-03-29T15:04:22Z" ,"c" : "+0.05" ,"c_fix" : "0.05" ,"cp" : "0.37" ,"cp_fix" : "0.37" ,"ccol" : "chg" ,"pcls_fix" : "13.69" } ]
```

Comment: Can you post the JSON in your question as well?

Comment: I'm pulling it from the Google finance site. It's in the JavaScript code.

Comment: Please post the JSON *within the question* to make the question complete.  You should not expect people to have to go get it when you're asking them to help you.  Also, without the JSON *within the question*, this question could become useless when that call one day returns something different.  This is a community - help us to help you :)

Comment: Your code seems to work as-is, assuming you're not mixing protocols (http and https).  I've changed it to https so it will work on JSFiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/sh8Lh1tk/

Comment: Yes I know, but I was asking how I could get the price so I don't have to click the button every time.

Comment: I agree, it works as expected, unless you are using http and issuing an https request or viceversa, the code works just fine.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see you asking the question of "How to get the price without clicking the button everytime" It says, clearly " I just need to get the updated price, then I'll go from there."

Comment: Nevermind. I'll delete the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**setInterval()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/Timers) to poll the server for a new price.

This will check it every 5000ms (5 seconds):

```
setInterval(getPrice, 5000);
```

**Snippet:**

```js
function getPrice() {
  if($('#stock').val()) {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'https://finance.google.com/finance/info?client=ig&q=' + $("#stock").val(),
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      success: function(json) {
        $("#stockprice").html(json[0]['l']);
        //do something with the new price
      }
    });
  }
}

getPrice();
setInterval(getPrice, 5000);
$('#stock').change(getPrice);  //get new price immediately when the input has changed
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="stock">
<div id="stockprice"></div>
```

Comment: I changed the second 'getPrice' to 'updatePrice' but now I get a 400 error

Comment: Sorry, I inadvertently duplicated the `getPrice()` function in the Snippet.  No need for a separate `updatePrice` function.

Comment: How can I make it so that if the box is empty, it doesn't try to get the data?

Comment: Put it in an `if` block:  `if($('#stock').val()) { $.ajax ... }`.  I've updated my Snippet.

Comment: Ok thanks. How come it doesn't work is I put `if($('#stock').val() != null)`

Comment: An empty string is not equal to the `null` constant.  You *could* do `if($('#stock').val() > '')`, but it's sufficient to simply check `if($('#stock').val())`.